# Having trouble deciphering my teachers pseudo code

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, nodes

Im working on a Binary Search Tree assignment for class and for this function I need to follow my professor's pseudo code. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about one specific detail, and she refuses to clarify.

Link to the pseudo code is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rit7e.jpg

```
SUBROUTINE insert(current, parent, node)
    IF current is null
        IF parent is null
            root = node
        ELSE
            ID node.value < parent.value
                parent.left = node
            ELSE
                parent.right = node
            END IF
            RETURN true
        END IF
    ELSE IF node.value = current.=value
        RETURN false
    ELSE IF ode.value < current.value
        insert(current.left, current, node)
    ELSE
        insert(current.right, current, node)
    END IF
END SUBROUTINE
```

In place of `node`, I've tried seemingly most of the allowed variables, including current, parent, (and even value, which didn't work. Shocker.)

```
bool recursiveInsert(Node* current, Node* parent, double value)
{

    if (current == NULL)
    {
        if (parent == NULL)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if (current->value < parent->value)
            {
                parent->left = current;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = current;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if(parent->value == current->value)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (parent->value < current->value)
    {
        insert(current->left, current->value, current);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(current->right, current->value, current);
    }   
}
```

I expect the output to add the value to the binary search tree and return true, but the program currently just throws a error whenever I get to the parts that require "node".

Comment: If `current==NULL` what does this do --> `current->value < parent->value` ?

Comment: Does your function always return a value?

Comment: Why do you feel you have to replace `node` with something else? Alternatively, what is the precise question you want answered? (And is it the same question as the one you asked your prof?)

Comment: Your teacher's pseudo-code seems to be missing `return` before the recursive calls to the function.

Comment: @rici If you look at the teachers 1975 puedo code it will make sense.

Comment: You should include the pseudo-code as text: it is easy to do.  You don't seem to have an argument corresponding to `node` in the pseudo-code, which makes it hard to get your function to correspond to your teacher's pseudo-code.

Comment: @bailey: the pseudocode looks fine to me. But the post is still missing a question.

Comment: @rici The pseudo is fine. Gavin didnt follow it at all. He mixed up parameters but I cant type a full answer on my phone!!!!

Comment: You don't seem to have a variable `root` either.  That presumably is a global variable — it isn't defined in the pseudo-code.  And the `node` argument appears to be a structure type.  You've not actually stated what question you asked your teacher; how are we meant to guess what you asked?  And you've not shown how you expect the function to be called.  That might matter.

Comment: @bailey: I think we all know what is wrong. But the rules here are that *you have to actually ask a question*. "Fix my code for me" is not a question. Learning how to ask precise questions is an important skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node` in the context of the pseudocode is a previously allocated node containing the data being inserted into the tree. The initial caller allocates it (which is both pointless and never done in RW code).In reality, it is highly unlikely to actually do this pattern unless you're considering a library that potentially *moves* nodes out of one tree into another, and you want to avoid the expense of setting-up/tearing-down the nodes themselves.

Regarding the algorithm, it's fairly straightforward, though not very pretty:

1. If both `current` and `parent` are null, it means this must be the first node in the tree tracked by some global pointer `root`. Therefore, `root` is assigned the incoming node directly.
2. Otherwise, If `current` is null but `parent` is *not* if means `parent` is some potential leaf in the tree (meaning it has either a left, a right, or both contained pointers that are null), and you've landed on the null pointer. The insertion requires comparing against the parent value to know whether you hang the node on the left or the right. Note that this is inefficient, as you already did this comparison (it's how you got here in the first place).
3. Otherwise if `current` is not-null we simply check whether the values are equal, or less (greater is assumed if neither of those are true), and drive into the subtree of left or right if warranted. In that case, `current.left` or `current.right` become the recursed `current`, and `current` becomes the `parent` of said-same recursive call.

That's it. That's how that algorithm works. And frankly, it's marginal.

To implement this algorithm with your argument list (that takes a value rather than a node for the final argument), you need only ensure node allocation only happens when it is time to actually hang it, and **only** then (there are two such cases.

```
bool recursiveInsert(Node* current, Node* parent, double value)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (current == NULL)
    {
        if (parent == NULL)
        {
            root = malloc(sizeof *root);
            root->value = value;
            root->left = root->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
            p->value = value;
            p->left = p->right = NULL;

            if (value < parent->value)
            {
                parent->left = p;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = p;
            }
            result = true;
        }
    }
    else if (value < parent->value)
        result = recursiveInsert(current->left, current, value);

    else if (parent->value < value)
        result = recursiveInsert(current->right, current, value);

    return result;
}
```

When inserting a value into the tree, the call will look something like this:

```
recursiveInsert(root, NULL, value);
```

It's not pretty, but it works. That it relies on global `root` presence is probably the worst part of this algorithm. The multi-compare is probably second on the list of yuck.

---

## A Different Approach

Ideally the root of the tree is passed in as an argument. Further, we can make the algorithm recursive as it is now, but no longer rely on some global `root`. Finally, we can reduce the argument count to two: the address of a pointer (initially the address of the root pointer), and the value being inserted. sing a pointer-to-pointer as the tree access method makes this algorithm elegant, whether using recursion or not. Both are provided below:

### Recursive Insertion

```
bool treeInsert(Node **pp, double value)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (!*pp)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        (*pp)->value = value;
        (*pp)->left = (*pp)->right = NULL;
        result = true;
    }
    else if (value < (*pp)->value)
    {
        result = recursiveInsert(&(*pp)->left, value);
    }
    else if ((*pp)->value < value)
    {
        result = recursiveInsert(&(*pp)->right, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Iterative Insertion

```
bool treeInsert(Node **pp, double value)
{
    bool result = false;

    while (*pp)
    {
        if (value < (*pp)->value)
            pp = &(*pp)->left;

        else if ((*pp)->value < value)
            pp = &(*pp)->right;

        else break;
    }

    if (!*pp)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        (*pp)->value = value;
        (*pp)->left = (*pp)->right = NULL;
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

in either case, you invoke by passing the address of the root pointer (thus a pointer to pointer), where an empty try is signified by a NULL root:

```
treeInsert(&root, value);
```

Either function will accomplish the task at hand. I leave the error-hardening asa task for you (check your mallocs).

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, this is a function to insert a node in a binary search tree. The parameters are as follows

1. `parent` is the parent of the node being examined. This would be called with the **root** of the tree.
2. `current` is the left or right of the parent node being examined. While calling the function for the first time, you should use `root->left` if the value of the current node is less than root, or `root->right` if the value is greater than `root`. If `root` is null, then `current` should also be `NULL`

   ```
   if (root == NULL)
   {
       ret = recursiveInsert(NULL, NULL, node);
   } 
   else if (root->value < node->value)     
   {
       ret = recursiveInsert(root->left, root, node);
   }
   else if (root-> value > node->value)
   {
       ret = recursiveInsert(root->right, root, node);
   }
   else 
   {
       //same value, handle error
   }
   ```
3. `node` is the new node to be added to the tree. The memory allocation for this node should be done before the call to `recursiveinsert` and the value should be specified.

Now let us look at the code that you have written.

The first mistake is to have the third parameter as a `double`. This should be a parameter of type `node` which should have already been allocated before.

From the condition check that

```
ELSE IF node.value = current.=value
    RETURN false
```

it seems that `node->value` is of integer type.

Taking all this into consideration, the updated code is below.

```
Node* root = NULL;  //global variable
...
bool recursiveInsert(Node* current, Node* parent, Node* node)
{

    if (current == NULL)
    {
        if (parent == NULL)
        {
            root = node;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current->value < parent->value)
            {
                parent->left = node;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = node;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if(node->value == current->value)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (parent->value < current->value)
    {
        recursiveInsert(current->left, current, node);
    }
    else
    {
        recursiveInsert(current->right, current, node);
    }   
}
```